# Using regex in logstash to filter files by name

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am pulling in a series of files and using logstash to filter out only the ones i need based on a regex before outputting the matched files to a named directory, but the regex is not working and nothing is being filtered out.

```
output {
    if [filename] =~ /.*[abc|def].*/
 {
        file {
        path => "/my/directory/%{filename}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}.log"
        codec => line { format => "%{message}"}
        }
    }
}
```

Incoming files are of the format:

```
P01_abc_stdout.log-2020-11-10-11.log
P01_rtf_stdout.log-2020-11-10-11.log
P01_ccc_stdout.log-2020-11-10-11.log
P01_def_stdout.log-2020-11-10-11.log
P01_ces_stdout.log-2020-11-10-11.log
```

but all of these files have come through, even though I'd expect it only to match

```
P01_abc_stdout.log-2020-11-10-11.log
P01_def_stdout.log-2020-11-10-11.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [filename] =~ /.*[abc|def].*/
```

Square brackets define a character group, so that will match any file that contains one of the characters a through f, or pipe. All of your filenames contain stdout, which includes a d, so they all match. The leading and trailing .* are not needed, since the pattern is not anchored. Try

```
if [filename] =~ /(abc|def)/
```